# Getting /usr/local/gcc-8.2/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjsoncpp.so.1), why?

Tags: compiling, gcc

Getting

```
/usr/local/gcc-8.2/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjsoncpp.so.1)
```

why?

I keep getting this error.

Most recently I tried to run `cmake` and got it.

It has happened more than once.

I am on Ubuntu 20.04, everything is up to date, so I assume `gcc` is as well.  Yet this has happened more than once recently.

If I do the strings thing as other posts have recommended, it shows up, which makes is even more strange.

Why does this happen, what does it mean, how did this get past the people who maintain the code, and how can I fix it?

Comment: `/usr/local/gcc-8.2/lib64/` isn't a directory that would normally exist and usually wouldn't be somewhere that the dynamic linker would search for libraries - it suggests you manually installed some software and/or manually configured the linker path (either with `ldconfig` or by setting a `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable) Do you recall doing something like that?

Comment: The LD_LIBRARY_PATH was set to that after this happened last time and a comment said to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to that.  I have set it to LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH now.  Do I need to reload .bashrc in some way to make it work?  Or just restart a terminal?

Comment: Normally, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` should not be set at all - my recommendation would be to `unset` it. If it needs to be set for a particular application, then write a "wrapper script" for that application that sets the environment only locally

Answer (score 0):

Usually such essential libraries should not be placed in `/usr/local/lib`.

So you have to move problematic library out the way with command below

```
mkdir ~/from-usr-local
sudo mv /usr/local/gcc-8.2/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 ~/from-usr-local/
```

or move whole problematic folder out the way by

```
sudo mv /usr/local/gcc-8.2 ~/from-usr-local/
```

and retry.

Please note that all essential system-wide software is contained in the repositories. While having them in `/usr/local` will cause issues, as you already see. You can install all needed system stuff by using below command

```
sudo apt-get install cmake gcc gcc-8 build-essential --reinstall
```

and then retry running `cmake`. If issue persists - then carefully inspect the contents of `/usr/local` .